# How can I make GDB print 64 bit variables?

Tags: gdb, 64-bit

I'm using GDB to debug code that was assembled with

`nasm -felf64 -Fdwarf`

when I want to examine the value at a label symbol, say

`var_h: dq -1`

using

`print var_h`

GDB assumes that the value is 32-bit and only gives me the lowest 4 bytes

`x \1gx $var_h`

gives an error along the lines of "cannot convert value to integer'

Very grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
(gdb) x/gx &var_h
```

Your other commands, as well as "along the lines of ..." make no sense.

Details *matter*, and you should always show *actual* commands you used and output you received, not vague approximations thereof.

Comment: Page 200 of the gdb manual lists `&` prefix as an operator - but that's the only reference.  Would never have found it otherwise.  Greatly appreciated and comments noted.

Comment: @Anding: GDB expressions mostly work like C syntax (not assembly), so a bare symbol name is implicitly dereferenced to get the value at the address of that symbol.